# Is it possible to connect an android application to an network database over wi-fi?

Tags: android, delphi

Is it possible to connect an android application on the phone to an network database that resides on a network over the wi-fi ?

Since I am very much new to this if someone could possibly provide me with a simple answer or a link. From what I could read it seems you must use http. What components do you use in Delphi Seattle (if http)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use a Client/Server approach you can't do it with the components that ship with Delphi. An option is [UniDAC](https://www.devart.com/unidac/)

My suggestion is that you roll a multi-tier solution, with Datasnap it's very easy. You should check the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Developing_DataSnap_Applications)

You could also use a [REST](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/REST) server or [EMS](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Enterprise_Mobility_Services) if your client can afford it